# Adding a bytearray as a key to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting this error while adding a bytearray as a key to a dictionary:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
```

Here is the code:

```
str_dict = {}
s = bytearray(10)

for x in range(0, 10):
    value = get_str(s)
    str_dict[s] = value
```

So I create a bytearray and the function get_str(s) updates the s and returns a 'value'. I want to add both the value and updated s to a dictionary. I get the above error.

Comment: If you have to use a list-like something as a dictionary key then use a tuple.

Comment: "A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys." From https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 6):

```
{[1, 2, 3]: 1}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

A dict key has to be a immutable type.

List or bytearray can't be use as a key because they are mutable and for this reason can't be unique since they can be changed.

---

It seems that if an object as a `__hash__` method it can be use as a key though :

[I'm able to use a mutable object as a dictionary key in python. Is this not disallowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418741/im-able-to-use-a-mutable-object-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-is-this-not-disa)

Comment: Can I covert the bytearray to an immutable type before addiing then?

Comment: As pasztorpisti suggest in comment to your question you may consider transforming it in tuple, though I don't know if this is possible, you can try it...

Comment: @Richard: Yep: `tuple(bytearray_instance)`

Comment: I need to be able to sort it based on the 'value". Does a tuple let me do that?

Comment: user220201: Yes, a list of tuples can be sorted.

Comment: I don't know why you need to use a bytearray as key, but I guess you may use the tuple as the key and store your bytearray beside other value in a sub-dict {(TUPLE): {'val1': '...', 'original_bytearray: BYTEARRAY}}

Comment: If you need to sort by the variable `value`, can you use the variable `value` as the key and the bytearray as the value of the dict.

Comment: The problem is value is not unique. Only the bytearray is unique. Is there another data structure that allows adding duplicates?

Comment: You may also, just keep an index of your unique bytearray and use the index as your unique key of your dict, which could avoid convertion back and forth between tuple and bytearray...

Answer (score 1):

Unhashable/immutable objects can't be used as keys because you may not find them after you've put them in the mapping :-)

```
x = [1, 2]
# suppose this works
mapping = {x: "this is x"}
# change x
x.append(3)
```

Thinking of how a mapping is actually implemented (buckets by hash), we (may) now have a key in the wrong bucket (`[1, 2, 3]` in `[1, 2]`'s bucket). We are **never** going to find it.

You can create a `string`, or use a `tuple` (both are immutable) and use them as keys.