# How do I make a set of tuples of sets?

Tags: python, set

I understand that a set is not hashable and a tuple is. However,

```
a = ({1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5})
b = ({1, 7}, {3, 0})
{a, b}
```

returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'.
Why is that so?

EDIT:
Yes, sets are mutable and therefore unhashable. However, tuples, even though being immutable, can have their elements change value AND still remain hashable. Like so:

```
class I() :
    __init__(self, value) :
        self.value = value
    __incr__(self) :
        self.value += 1
tup = (I(), I())
tup[0].incr()
```

So why is it not allowed when it's a tuple of sets?

Comment: Briefly: because it doesn't make sense for mutable objects to be hashable.

Comment: There is an answer for that in [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755990/why-can-tuples-contain-mutable-items)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 his question wasn't actually why set's not hashable, he asked why tuples containing sets is not hashable, which is actually a different question for someone who does not understand how tuples work in Python. Anyway, it is explained in the link I posted. Just wanted to point out it is not an exact duplicate of the question you presented.

Comment: @Rockybilly, yeah, thanks, that's closer to my question
However, why is a tuple of mutable objects is still hashable, when a tuple of sets is not? How is any mutable object different from a set?

Comment: A tuple of mutable objects is not hashable.(And tuples are not mutable.) Except some cases which is explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418741/im-able-to-use-a-mutable-object-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-is-this-not-disa) question

Comment: You could make a tuple of *frozenset*s if you want something hashable.

Answer (score 1):

since no one really answered the question, and googlers want quick answer:

```
my_set = {(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)}
```

Defines set of tuples

Answer (score 0):

as you have already mentioned correctly, Python has both modifiable and non-changeable datatypes. Also correct is that a set is a mutable datatype, while a tuple is a non-changeable datatype. **However, this is only true for the first level of a tuple and not for deeper levels**, so it is not true for your objects.

Let us illustrate this principle with an example:

```
t = ([1,1],[2,2])
id(t) # --> 2588744372096
```

o we have a tuple `t` that contains two lists. One could now assume that this tuple could not be changed, because although lists can be changed, tuples cannot. Internally the following happens: The tuple does not directly contain two lists, but in the tuple pointers are stored to the lists. So the element of the tuple at index `0` is a pointer to the list `[1,1]` and at position `1` is a pointer to the list `[2,2]`. So we can change the list at will without changing the tuple, because it consists only of pointers that do not change. So let's change the first element of the first list:

```
t[0][0] = 3
print(t) # --> ([3,1],[2,2])
id(t) # --> 2588744372096
```

As we can see from the same id of the tuple, it is still the same tuple, the contents of the tuple (the pointers) have not changed either.

You can take a look at the website [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), which also shows this aspect graphically. The graphical visualization is also available here: [Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk8dB.png). Further information about pointers can be found here: [Information about pointers](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html)

Best regards
Johannes :)