# Issue of feeding in feed_dict (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

My raw_data is PTB dataset.
I am generating batches by the following code.

```
def generate_batches(raw_data, batch_size, unrollings):
  global data_index
  data_len = len(raw_data)
  num_batches = data_len // batch_size
  inputs = []
  labels = []
  print (num_batches, data_len, batch_size)
  for j in xrange(unrollings) : 
      inputs.append([])
      labels.append([])
      for i in xrange(batch_size) :   
        inputs[j].append(raw_data[i + data_index])
        labels[j].append(raw_data[i + data_index + 1])    
      data_index = (data_index + batch_size) % len(raw_data)
  return inputs, labels
```

In session run, the same batches generated are fed in feed_dict as in the following code.

```
for step in xrange(num_steps) :
batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_batches(train_dataset, batch_size, unrollings=5) 
feed_dict = dict()
for i in range(unrollings):
    feed_dict = {train_inputs : batch_inputs,  train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions, lr = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction, learning_rate], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

The training input and labels are as follows :

```
for _ in range(unrollings) :
 train_data.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32))
 train_label.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float32))
train_inputs = train_data[:unrollings]
train_labels = train_label[:unrollings]
```

First, I got the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`to which I converted the list of batch_input to tuple using `tuple(batch_input[i])` which is explained clearly in [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list). 
Resolved : Then I get this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. 
.

Comment: you are trying to use ndarray as the key of your dictionary, it should be a string

Comment: thanks +1 i corrected the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how `feed_dict` works. But first of all, python dict doesn't accept any instances of unhashable class as key. Both list and numpy.ndarray are not allowed to use as dict key (even if you wrap it with a tuple). I found [list post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418741/im-able-to-use-a-mutable-object-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-is-this-not-disa) explains about dict key.

**How feed_dict works**

In your graph, there should be placeholders created as symbolic tensors. Assume that your raw data is 2D: (num_samples, num_features), with the first dimension corresponds to the size of samples and the second dimension corresponds to the num of features. Assume the labels are one-hot encoded and have num_classes in total.

```
train_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, num_features], dtype=tf.float32)
train_labels = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, num_classes], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then in your session when setting up feed_dict, you use those symbolic placeholder tensor as key and the sampled batch_data as value.

```
feed_dict = {train_data:batch_inputs, train_labels:batch_labels}
```