# Caching tensorflow results on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tensorflow how do I keep my result of `session.run(some_tensors,...)` on the GPU and then use it back again to feed feed_dicts?

Edit:::   Here is a concrete example of why I need this.
So I have data (multi dimensional tensors) with multiple RNNs running over them. But the data is so huge that I cannot process one sample on the GPU. Therefore I break the sample in parts and run them through RNNs. But this means I need to save the final states of RNNs after processing the 1st part and then pass it on to the RNNs processing the next part.
Right now I evaluate the part1 RNN's state using `session.run()` and bring them on to CPU and then again pass these into feed_dicts for evaluating the next part of the data and so on.

Comment: Please add some code to your question to help us help you. This is a good example question also using using `fill_feed_dict`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477927/issue-of-feeding-in-feed-dict-tensorflow

Comment: The results stored in tensors are on the GPU already (if GPU computation enabled of course). Why do you want to do `session.run(some_tensors, ...)`? Some more context to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to do `sess.partial_run_setup` followed by `sess.partial_run`.

As of r1.3, this is still "EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change."

`sess.partial_run_setup`
Sets up a graph with feeds and fetches for a partial run.

`sess.partial_run`
Continues the execution with more feeds and fetches.

More info at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session