# Proper way of choosing the right corresponding class in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django and have a few models. They correlate to each other without any foreign keys, but I want to be able to select them in a centralized place, here are the models (without the inheritance and fields so tests are easy):

```
class ItemTypeOne:
    pass

class ItemOneExtra:
    pass

# -----------------------------
class ItemTypeTwo:
    pass

class ItemTwoExtra:
    pass

# ... and so on
```

What I thought of using so far its a dict to map them, like so:

```
correlated_extra_model = {ItemTypeOne: ItemOneExtra, ItemTypeTwo: ItemTwoExtra}[ItemTypeOne]
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it's acceptable

Comment: Any reason in particular to not use foreign keys if they correlate to each other?

Comment: This could be relevant to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418741/im-able-to-use-a-mutable-object-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-is-this-not-disa

Comment: Yes, they are both from separated apps and I want the extra models to be an additional feature, not related to the main one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in a relational setting, your tables are related only if you have sort of foreign key or one-to-one field pointing to another table. Without it, it does not any relation at db level. You may be enforcing this behaviour through your logic.

Secondly, if you have to create an auxiliary models for each of your base model, I think it's an indicator that the current design is flawed and you need to rethink your models. Of course, this is based on my assumptions and they might not be very much applicable to your use case. So, if you can, please share some more details about the problem statement.

Comment: I don't want them to be related in a db level. Think of this approach the same you would if I had simple classes instead of models. Maybe I should just delete the question and ask again just for python

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta, if you do get the answer to this question, could you just post a reference to that answer in here. It would be a lot of help.

Comment: I'd rather wait for other answers, I'm using the solution provided in the question until I get more info on the subject